# Eclipse UML plugin to generate Java Source code

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

Is there an Eclipse plugin that can draw uml class diagram and then generate Java source code from the class diagram?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first Eclipse plug in I came across.

[Altova - UML Eclipse Integration](http://www.altova.com/umodel/eclipse-integration.html)

> Automatic synchronization between the UModel project and source code lets you refer to – and work in – either the UML software model or the source code editor, confident that both windows display the current project status. Every change you make in one window is immediately reflected in the other.

Here's a list of [Eclipse plug ins](http://eclipse-plugins.2y.net/eclipse/plugins.jsp?category=UML) that are categorized under UML.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool is EclipseUML Omondo. 
Altova is not really an Eclipse plugin but a standalone application built with Eclipse !!

Answer (score 0):

[MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-19.html) is pretty neat but it is not free.

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) is a nice free UML IDE that can generate source from your class diagrams. There is an [Eclipse plugin](http://argoeclipse.tigris.org/) version for it as well. I haven't used the Eclipse plugin version of it so can't comment. But if it does the same as the standalone version it should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Papyrus, which is an Eclipse plugin, Papyrus can draw UML diagrams and generate C++ or Java source files.